# Issue in moving header image in html5

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

this is my code:

```
<header>
    <div id='animate-area'>
    </div>
  </header>
```

**css:**

```
@keyframes animatedBackground {
      from { background-position: 0 0; }
      to { background-position: 100% 0; }
    }
    @-webkit-keyframes animatedBackground {
      from { background-position: 0 0; }
      to { background-position: 100% 0; }
    }
    @-moz-keyframes animatedBackground {
      from { background-position: 0 0; }
      to { background-position: 100% 0; }
    }
    #animate-area { 
      height: 145px;
      background-image: url(http://s10.postimg.org/noxw294zd/banner.png);
      animation: animatedBackground 40s linear infinite;
      -ms-animation: animatedBackground 40s linear infinite;
      -moz-animation: animatedBackground 40s linear infinite;
      -webkit-animation: animatedBackground 40s linear infinite;
    }
```

This is JsFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/6d6xa65n/

When run this image-src="img/banner.png" it will show different output. but when i add image src="http://s10.postimg.org/noxw294zd/banner.png", it shows something different from actual output, after completing one time of rotation, need to start from left. and need to remove space left and right side of image.

How to fix this? Can someone help me with us?

This is image i used https://i.stack.imgur.com/uPV7V.jpg

Comment: Yeah, I've found this good [article](http://css-tricks.com/infinite-all-css-scrolling-slideshow/) and tried to apply to your case (see [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6d6xa65n/3/)), but I can't explain the odd percentages. As soon as I'll get it, I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I got it right, you need to make these changes:

To remove extra space:

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

To make your image rotate back and forth:

```
@keyframes animatedBackground {
  0% { background-position: 0 0; }
  50% { background-position: 100% 0; }
  100% { background-position: 0 0; }
}
```

See working [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6d6xa65n/2/).

**Edit:**

I've found this [article](http://css-tricks.com/infinite-all-css-scrolling-slideshow/) with basics on how to do the infinite image scroll. But I couldn't make it work with relative width and height (so as author of the technique in his demo), so I've just multiplied original width (1269px) accordingly. Here is the final css:

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#slideshow {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 100px;
}
#animate-area { 
    height: 100%;
    width: 2538px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;

    background-image: url('http://s10.postimg.org/noxw294zd/banner.png');
    animation: animatedBackground 40s linear infinite;
    -ms-animation: animatedBackground 40s linear infinite;
    -moz-animation: animatedBackground 40s linear infinite;
    -webkit-animation: animatedBackground 40s linear infinite;
}
/* Put your css in here */
@keyframes animatedBackground {
    from { left: 0; }
    to { left: -1269px; }
}
@-webkit-keyframes animatedBackground {
    from { left: 0; }
    to { left: -1269px; }
}
@-moz-keyframes animatedBackground {
    from { left: 0; }
    to { left: -1269px; }
}
```

So `#animate-area` is twice as large as image and we just animate to left on full image size. See updated [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6d6xa65n/4/).

Comment: I m asking like, if the image rotated once right, again it will start from right, did you got my question?.. from your answer, after completed 1 time rotation, again it started from left and moved